# how to Back up azure cloudservice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Is there a way I can back up my azure cloud service(  backup of .pkg and .cscfg files) .

We have an existing azure cloud service deployed an year ago. Now we don't have either the old version the source code nor the setup files (.pkg file and the .cscfg files ). We want to create a backup of the  current cloud service .  We created a new version of our cloud service and tried to do a VIP swap which didn't worked as (Windows Azure cannot perform a VIP swap between deployments that have a different number of endpoints.) our new version has many new changes which are not compatible with old version .

I need to find a way to take a backup of .pkg and .cscfg files from existing deployment in cloud . 
Any suggestions /workarounds for this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a **Get Package** operation on the service management API that can retrieve the .cscfg and .cspkg files from a Cloud Service deployment.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154121.aspx

You could also try Cerebrata's Azure Management Studio (AMS).  AMS contains a "Save Package" button in the Cloud (Hosted) Service deployment.  I'm assuming AMS is using the same API to download the .cscfg and .cspkg files.  Done in a few button clicks.  :)

Comment: AMS doesn't let you save it locally though.